# Improve performance of double - java

Tags: java, double

Here is a simple code snippet of java

```
float start = System.nanoTime();
for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i = i+1){}
float end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Time taken : " + (end-start)/1000000000);
```

This gives output `0.004194304` seconds where as :

```
for(double i=0;i<1000000000;i = i+1){}
```

this code where I just changed the type of `i` from `int` to `double` takes `3.8970327` seconds. My question is how to improve this really bad performance of double in java

Comment: Yes, adding 1 to an `int` is a lot simpler than adding 1 to a `double`. Is this a bottleneck in your *real* code?

Comment: if you want a numeric range bigger than `int` then use `long` instead of `double` type.

Comment: I suspect that in the `int` case the loop has been optimized away.  Anyway - JAFMB - "just another flawed micro-benchmark".

Comment: Mandatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think your `int` benchmark is giving a specious answer.  The number simply fails the common sense test!!

Incrementing from 1 to 1,000,000,000 should perform 1 billion increments, 1 billion stores, 1 billion tests, 1 billion branches.  All of that is *supposedly* happening in ~0.004 seconds.  That implies a 4 billion instructions in 0.004 seconds, or 1 trillion instructions in 1 second ... or a clock rate of some multiple of 1.0E12.  But the fastest intel processors around have clock rate less than 10 GHz ... or 1.0E10.

In fact, what I think has happened is that the JIT compiler has figured out that your loop is doing no useful work, and has *optimized it away*.

For some reason, the JIT compiler has not figured out that the version with the `double` is also not doing useful work either.

But either way, 1 billion floating point operations in 3 seconds using a single processor is pretty good performance ...

> My question is how to improve this really bad performance of double in java

1. It is not really bad performance.
2. It is (approximately) real performance ... and the `int` performance you are seeing is bogus.
3. You can't improve on it.

---

Actually, you are kind of lucky that the `double` loop terminates at all.  Consider this version:

```
 for (double i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i = i + 1){}

 for (float i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i = i + 1){}
```

The `float` version should be faster.  Right?

Wrong!

The problem is that a `float` only has 24 bits (7.22 decimal digits) of precision.  So, somewhere between 1.0E7 and 1.0E8, you will get to a point where `i + 1` evaluates to `i` ... due to rounding.  That leads to an infinite loop.

When you think about it, it is this kind of thing that could cause the JIT compiler to not optimize away a floating point loop.

Comment: Yeah!!.....You are right. The compiler optimized the code by itself. I tried doing some O(1) stuff in the loop and then it needed an execution time of 1.6 seconds.  But I do not get how `i+1` evaluates to `i` if `float` is used. I am sorry if this question is trivial but I don't get it. As far as I know the number should get truncated at the last or should wrap to the beginning.

Comment: Re: the float example, try it and see!!  Remember that `i` is a `float` not an `int`, and that *therefore* `i + 1` is a floating point operation.  Floating point operations do not wrap around or truncate.  Instead, the notional result of the operation is *rounded* to the nearest value that is representable as an IEE 32 bit floating bit value.

Comment: Then you need to understand that as IEE floating point numbers get larger, the "gaps" between successive values get larger.  At some point, the gap will be > 2.0, and you will find there is a case where `i + 1.0` gets rounded to `i` ... as being the nearest *representable* floating point number.

Answer (score -1):

It's normal because a int take 4 bytes in memory while double takes 8 bytes (it has decimals).
Maybe you can prove BigDecimal.

Comment: And your last sentence makes no sense.

Comment: I edited and change float by int. I said why it's slower double than int. just did it